# Javascript Files are not loading properly with the error "data is not defined" ? Website working offline properly

Tags: javascript

`uncaught reference error - data is not defined`. None of the javascript (.js) files on my website loads properly that is why the website layout is not working properly. it displays errors in javascript console of inspector window of chrome. I have tried a lot but unable to solve the problem, whereas when I run the website offline it works properly without any type of error.

I have tried a lot online by rearranging the javascript files but none of my efforts works. always the same error `uncaught reference error - data is not defined`

```
  y || (data, _0x43cf("0x22"), _0x43cf("0x23"), function() {
```

line number 124 of theme.js, data is not defined?

Comment: is `data` retrieved via API? might need more than 1 line of code to see what's wrong

Comment: i can send you the complete source code. its working offline but not online. give me ur mail id. it is a static website you can also get source code problems via www.majesticmarbles.com